# TypeError: slice indices must be integers in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, thus the question,

I'm trying to slice an array and find the sub array of the longest length that is less than a particular value. This is my code,

```
def main():
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    print(maxLength(a, 3))


def maxLength(a, k):
    max = 0
    currTotal = 0

    for i in enumerate(a):
        for j in enumerate(a):
            temp = a[i:i+j:1]
            currTotal += a[j]
            if currTotal < k:
                if len(temp) > max:
                    max = len(temp)

        currTotal = 0
    return max


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong with the Slice, any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `i` and `j` are? Have you tried printing them?

Comment: There is only one line where you are using slices: `temp = a[i:i+j:1]`. Only variables used in this slice are `i` and `j`. Have you checked what they contain (and how that's differs from what you expect)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), it gives you a sequence of tuples.

```
for i,x in enumerate(mylist):
    # i is the index
    # x is the item at that index
```

You are assigning that tuple to one variable:

```
for i in enumerate(a):
    # i is a tuple of (index, item)
```

And then you are trying to use `i` like it is an integer. It's not an integer.

If you want just an integer, use:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
         ...
```

Answer (score -1):

`enumerate` returns an `object`. Thats why it is giving you that error.

if you want to traverse the array, try `range(len(a))` instead.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            temp = a[i:i+j:1]
            currTotal += a[j]
            if currTotal < k:
                if len(temp) > max:
                    max = len(temp)
```

Comment: You can actually use integer objects or the `None` object for slicing. And slices aren't a function.